# How can I set the text color of an NSButton via Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, nsbutton

There are several questions about how to set the text color programmatically.  That's all fine, but there's got to be a way to do it via Interface Builder also.

The "Show Fonts" box works for changing the *size* of the button text, but Xcode ignores any color changes made using the widget there, and the Attributes Inspector for NSButton doesn't have a color picker...

Answer (score 5):

I've no idea why this is missing still from NSButton. But here is the replacement class in Swift 4:

```
import Cocoa

class TextButton: NSButton {
    @IBInspectable open var textColor: NSColor = NSColor.black
    @IBInspectable open var textSize: CGFloat = 10

    public override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
    }

    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let titleParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        titleParagraphStyle.alignment = alignment

        let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [.foregroundColor: textColor, .font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: textSize), .paragraphStyle: titleParagraphStyle]
        self.attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.title, attributes: attributes)
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution,i hope so you will get :)

```
NSFont *txtFont = button.font;
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[style setAlignment:button.alignment];
NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [NSColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, style, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, txtFont, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                      initWithString:button.title attributes:attrsDictionary];
[button setAttributedTitle:attrString];
```

Comment: @quemeful No you cant set, but you can able to set via runtime attribute is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add this extension to your code if you like the 'Throw an extension in and look if it sticks' approach.

```
extension NSButton {

  @IBInspectable open var textColor: NSColor? {
    get {
      return self.attributedTitle.attribute(.foregroundColor, at: 0, effectiveRange: nil) as? NSColor
    }
    set {
      var attributes = self.attributedTitle.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil)
      attributes[.foregroundColor] = newValue ?? NSColor.black
      self.attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.title,
                                                       attributes: attributes)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

*Edit: Misread question. Below is how you'd change the text of a button on an iOS app.*

Just to clarify, this isn't working for you?

- added button
- click on it and go to Attributes Inspector
- change color in "Text Color" field

[image: Changed button color to reddish]

Comment: The question is about an NSButton (for an OS X app, not an iPhone).  There isn't a "Text Color" field in the Attributes Inspector (at least not as of Xcode 6.1.1).